# Fourier Series Expansion of Periodic Signal

Tags: fourier

Why is it necessary for a periodic signal to be a power signal for its fourier series expansion to exist?

Answer (score 2):

If a signal is periodic, has an "infinite energy", but a finite average power, then it is a "power signal".

Periodic signals that do not have finite average power do not meet the [Dirichlet conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions) for the existence of the series expansion.

Comment: @DaveTweed : Tanks! sorry for my english! :)